# How to make Laravel migrations of SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm having some difficulties trying to make a laravel migration from SQL database, this is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `taxtype_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rnc` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ced` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address2` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sector` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`taxtype_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique Fields` (`rnc`,`code`,`ced`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and this is what ive been trying to do but its not working in the laravel database migration:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id',11)->unsigned();
    $table->integer('taxtype_id',10)->unsigned();
    $table->integer('code',11);
    $table->string('name', 100);
    $table->string('rnc');
    $table->string('ced');
    $table->mediumText('address');
    $table->mediumText('address2');
    $table->string('sector');
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('state');
    $table->string('country');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('website');
    $table->boolean('active');
    $table->timestamp('created_date');
    $table->string('created_by');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Does anyone have more experience to help me out on this migration? or guide me on what im doing wrong? when I run php artisan migrate i always get SQLSTATE[42000]: Synxtax error or access violation, any help would be really appreciate it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going with ButtonPiglet on this one, Laravel doesn't allow specifying lengths on integer fields. It is causing user_id, taxtype, and code to be auto_increment primary keys.

I change these three from

```
$table->integer('user_id',11)->unsigned();
$table->integer('taxtype_id',10)->unsigned();
$table->integer('code',11);
```

to this

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('taxtype_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('code');
```

and was able to run the migration just fine on my machine using laravel 5.2. Using integer() will set it to the length of 10 in DB. If you need anything smaller user tinyInteger(), smallInteger(), or mediumInteger(). For larger length use bigInteger()

Answer (score 0):

The laravel schema builder doesn't support specifying lengths of integer.  Remove the second argument from all your integer fields, or change them to tinyInteger, smallInteger, etc...

Comment: removing it still got errors, it says it doesnt allow 2 primary keys the SQL version is working perfectly im having problems with the laravel version

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution making use of DB::unprepared  to do some RAW sql, now its working good and it looks like this:

```
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('taxtype_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('code', 50);
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('rnc', 30);
        $table->string('ced', 30);
        $table->mediumText('address');
        $table->mediumText('address2');
        $table->string('sector', 100);
        $table->string('city', 100);
        $table->string('state', 100);
        $table->string('country', 100);
        $table->string('phone', 25);
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->string('website', 100);
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->date('created_date');
        $table->string('created_by', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->unique(array('code', 'rnc', 'ced'));
        $table->index(array('id', 'user_id'));

    });
    DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE `customers` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ,  `taxtype_id` )');
}
```

Thank you ButtonPiglet for the heads up and Thank you Andrew Nolan